# Load raster data with {terra} in {targets} pipeline

Tags: r, target

I'm trying to load a raster in a targets pipeline with the terra package.

The _targets.R file looks like this:

```
# Created by use_targets().
# Follow the comments below to fill in this target script.
# Then follow the manual to check and run the pipeline:
#   https://books.ropensci.org/targets/walkthrough.html#inspect-the-pipeline # nolint

# Load packages required to define the pipeline:
library(targets)
# library(tarchetypes) # Load other packages as needed. # nolint

# Set target options:
tar_option_set(
  packages = c(
    "tidyverse",
    "terra",
  ), # packages that your targets need to run
  format = "rds" # default storage format
  # Set other options as needed.
)

# tar_make_clustermq() configuration (okay to leave alone):
options(
  clustermq.scheduler = "multiprocess"
)

# tar_make_future() configuration (okay to leave alone):
# Install packages {{future}}, {{future.callr}}, and {{future.batchtools}} to allow use_targets() to configure tar_make_future() options.

# Run the R scripts in the R/ folder with your custom functions:
tar_source()
# source("other_functions.R") # Source other scripts as needed. # nolint

# Replace the target list below with your own:
list(
  ## Load all data in R/load_data.R
  tar_target(esg_rast_file, "data/ESGs/ESGs.tif", format="file"),
  tar_target(esg_rast_data, terra::rast(esg_rast_file))
)
```

My output looks like this:

```
r$> library(targets)

r$> tar_make()
â€¢ start target esg_rast_file
â€¢ built target esg_rast_file [6.42 seconds]
â€¢ start target esg_rast_data
â€¢ built target esg_rast_data [0.05 seconds]
â€¢ end pipeline [7.96 seconds]
 
r$> tar_load(esg_rast_data)
NULL value passed as symbol address
r$> esg_rast_data
class       : SpatRaster
Error in x@ptr$nrow() : external pointer is not valid
```

Is this what is supposed to happen? Am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to find anything online about these errors.  I'm also having trouble loading sf .shp data as well. Seems like I am missing something.

Comment: This might work better with the current version of terra

Comment: Thanks for the response Robert.  I updated to terra version 1.6.47 (latest CRAN release - is there a development version?) and am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Current terra supports direct RDS reading and writing of SpatRaster objects; so I thought that might fix this. Apparently not. I do not know what is going on behind the scenes in "pipelines"

Comment: Same error here with 16.4.53. Any solutions to this @MikeSchmidt?

Comment: No.  So far I've just been converting the SpatialRaster to another format such as a dataframe before I write it as a target.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this issue by using terra::wrap and the qs format. You can find an example here (plus some additional advice): https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/809

In your case, try

```
list(
  ## Load all data in R/load_data.R
  tar_target(esg_rast_file, "data/ESGs/ESGs.tif", format="file"),
  tar_target(esg_rast_data, terra::rast(esg_rast_file) |> terra::wrap(), format = "qs")
)
```

Comment: In subsequent targets using the wrapped raster (with "qs" storage format), I use `unwrap`  but get errors like:

```Error: [rast] file does not exist: C:/Users/bcaradima/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpA7X9BQ/spat_NfgbK7dNFku94UC_1520.tif```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Yep, I'm getting that error now too.